# Why 'undefined method `assert_equal' ' is thrown even after requiring 'test/unit'

Tags: ruby, testunit

I opened irb & entered:

```
require 'test/unit'
```

but when I used the `assert_equal` method, I got following error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'assert_equal' for main:Object`. Why is this happening even after requiring 'test/unit' ?

Answer (score 11):

`assert_equal` is defined on subclasses of `Test::Unit::TestCase`, so are only available in that class. You may have some success with `include Test::Unit::TestCase` to load those methods onto the current scope.

More likely you could be better writing your tests in a short file, and running them with `ruby ./my_file.rb`

Answer (score 11):

You can use in built ruby error testing

```
raise "Message you want to throw when error happens" if/unless "Condition when you want to throw the error "
```

**OR**

If you get error messages when trying to use assertions, like "NoMethodError: undefined method `assert' for main:Object", then add this to the top of your script:

```
require "test/unit/assertions"
include Test::Unit::Assertions
```

Answer (score 7):

This is how assertions are used:

```
class Gum
  def crisis; -42 end
end

# and as for testing:

require 'test/unit'

class GumTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_crisis
    g = Gum.new
    assert_equal -42, g.crisis
  end
end
```