# Undefined method: assert_equal

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I think the problem has to do with my test class inheritance. I checked several other threads on SO and they all seem to say to inherent from something different. Some of the classes to inherent from include:
[Minitest::Unit::TestCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361602/nomethoderror-undefined-method-assert-equal-with-minitest)
[Test::Unit::TestCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317921/why-undefined-method-assert-equal-is-thrown-even-after-requiring-test-unit)

What is the correct class to inherent from? Is there something else I am doing wrong here? Thanks! (;

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require './any'

class TestAny < Minitest::Test
  describe "Any returns true" do
    items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    assert_equal items.any? { |item| item.even?}, true, "Some items are even"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be using spec format but then use a matcher from the unit testing format. Also if you have a `describe` block, you need an `it` block inside. Have you tried this?

```
describe "Any returns true" do
  it "Some items are even" do
    items.any? { |item| item.even?}.must_equal true
  end
end
```

Comment: I still get: NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_equal' for #<Class:0x007fe394081d60>
    any_test.rb:8:in `block in test_any'

Comment: Yeah, that works. But why? I am following the tutorial on codeschool and they say to use asser_equal

Comment: `assert_equal` works in unit test style. Look at the documentation here and compare the two styles: http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/#label-SYNOPSIS%3A

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as below :-

```
require "minitest/autorun"

class TestAny < Minitest::Test
  def any_test
    items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    item_present = items.any? { |item| item.even? }

    assert_equal item_present, true, "Some items are even"
  end
end
```

Here is the test run:-

```
[arup@test]$ ruby test_any.rb
Run options: --seed 57100

# Running:



Finished in 0.001293s, 0.0000 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
[arup@test]$
```